# Unexpected end-of-input: expected close marker for Object (start marker at [Source: {; line: 1, column: 1]) at [Source: {; line: 1, column: 3]

Tags: java, json, jackson

I need to deserialize a `json` object using [`Jackson`](https://www.google.co.il/search?safe=strict&ei=6qyVWr2YIY-QkwW-jLXABA&q=jackson%20java&oq=jackson%20java&gs_l=psy-ab.3..35i39k1j0l5j0i20i263k1j0l3.12597.13249.0.13496.5.5.0.0.0.0.154.512.0j4.4.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..1.4.509...0i67k1.0.LV-SJnkU6mA).
After several efforts and internet search, all effort to resolve the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.fasterxml.jackson.core.io.JsonEOFException: Unexpected end-of-input: expected close marker for Object (start marker at [Source: {; line: 1, column: 1])
     at [Source: {; line: 1, column: 3]
```

have failed.

I tried [JacksonMixInAnnotations](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-docs/wiki/JacksonMixInAnnotations) without success.

An example of the json is

```
{
    "imageDigest": "sha256:7cc1145883e4e6741fd4f02b8d01636ac341038de51e7923b9a5acf98329602a", 
    "vulnerabilities": [
        {
            "fix": "None", 
            "package": "apt-1.0.9.8.4", 
            "severity": "Negligible", 
            "url": "https://security-tracker.debian.org/tracker/CVE-2011-3374", 
            "vuln": "CVE-2011-3374"
        }
    ], 
    "vulnerability_type": "os"
}
```

**My deserialization code:**

```
String line = "";
    File file = new File ("C:\\xxxxxxx\\xxxxxx\\kbastani-movie-microservice04.json");
    Anchore anchore = new Anchore();
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    BufferedReader breader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
    while((line= breader.readLine()) != null) {
    anchore = mapper.readValue(line, Anchore.class);
    System.out.println(anchore);
    List <Vulnerability> vulnerability = anchore.getVulnerabilities();
    System.out.println(vulnerability.get(1));

    }

    breader.close();
```

**Anchore class**

```
public class Anchore {
    @JsonProperty("imageDigest")
    private String imageDigest;
    @JsonProperty("vulnerabilities")
    private List<Vulnerability> vulnerabilities = null;
    @JsonProperty("vulnerability_type")
    private String vulnerabilityType;

    public Anchore() {
    }

     public Anchore(String imageDigest, List<Vulnerability> vulnerabilities, String vulnerabilityType) {
        super();
        this.imageDigest = imageDigest;
        this.vulnerabilities = vulnerabilities;
        this.vulnerabilityType = vulnerabilityType;
    }
}
```

**Vulnerability class**

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Vulnerability {

        @JsonProperty("fix")
        private String fix;
        @JsonProperty("package")
        private String imagePackage;
        @JsonProperty("severity")
        private String severity;
        @JsonProperty("url")
        private String url;
        @JsonProperty("vuln")
        private String vuln;

        public Vulnerability() {
        }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

when you call `breader.readLine()`, you read a single line.
You need to read the whole json before calling `mapper.readValue(line, Anchore.class);`, this should be outside the loop.

- read the whole file into a string
- transform the string into your object with the ObjectMapper.

edit: to read a file:

```
String path = "C:\\xxxxxxxxxx\\xxxxxxxxxx\\kbastani-movie-microservice04.json";
byte[] encoded = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(path));
String json = new String(encoded, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
anchore = mapper.readValue(json, Anchore.class);
```

Comment: still same error even after following your recommendation : `while((line=breader.readLine()) != null) {`
  `myString = line; }`
  `anchore = mapper.readValue(myString
    , Anchore.class);`
  `vulnerability = anchore.getVulnerabilities();`
  `for (Vulnerability vulns : vulnerability) {`
               `System.out.println(vulns.getFix()); }`

Comment: like I said, you need to read the whole file, not only the first line (that's what getLine does), I updated my answer.

Comment: Wow it works perfectly. thanks :). I misunderstood you when you mentioned "loop". So I basically need no loop here, this is new to me. Thanks for another lesson.

Answer (score 2):

You n have few mistakes

- You need to read the all file before you parsing your json to an object
- You trying to get `vulnerability.get(1)` while you have only one `vulnerability` in your json.

Here is a simple & cleaner way to achieve what you are looking for :

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.List;


public class MainJackson {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        Path jsonPath = Paths
                .get("jsonPath.json")
                .toAbsolutePath();

        String jsonText = Files.lines(jsonPath)
                .reduce("", String::concat);


        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

        Anchore anchore = mapper.readValue(jsonText, Anchore.class);
        System.out.println(anchore);

        List<Vulnerability> vulnerability = anchore.getVulnerabilities();
        System.out.println(vulnerability.get(0));

    }
}
```

Comment: this also works excellently. Thanks, unfortunately I already accepted @Syl's answer. But you have taught me something new today also. Thanks.